emmeans and mmrm when there are missing timepoints
I use the mrmm package to fit a model for repeated mesures.
I use a structured covariance matrix, ante-dependence (ad).
I kept unobserved timepoints in order to keep the correct distance between the observed time points.
However, it seems to create problem when then I want to use emmeans to compute estimated marginal means:
error in crossprod(x y) non-conformable arguments

So I don't know what I should do... Do you have any idea ?
Thank you very much
Here is my code:
library(emmeans)
library(mmrm)

data$VISIT=factor(data$VISIT,levels=c("WEEK 1", "WEEK 5", "WEEK 9", "WEEK 13", "WEEK 17", "WEEK 21",    "WEEK 25", "WEEK 29", "WEEK 33", "WEEK 37", "WEEK 41", "WEEK 45"
)) # Adding some levels to keep 4 weeks between the timepoints


fit <- mmrm(
    formula = value ~  VISIT*group +  ad(VISIT | Patient),
    data = data,
    drop_visit_levels = TRUE
)
emmeans(fit, ~ group |VISIT) #OK

fit1 <- mmrm(
    formula = value ~  VISIT*group +  ad(VISIT | Patient),
    data = data,
    drop_visit_levels = FALSE
)
emmeans(fit1, ~ group |VISIT) # error in crossprod(x y) non-conformable arguments

And here is my data:



Patient
group
VISIT
value




P1
A
WEEK 1
-0.3291093


P1
A
WEEK 5
0.7164096


P1
A
WEEK 9
-0.4425356


P1
A
WEEK 13
1.2678470


P1
A
WEEK 21
-0.9114589


P1
A
WEEK 29
-1.4467151


P1
A
WEEK 37
2.0110589


P1
A
WEEK 45
-0.2369511


P2
B
WEEK 1
2.1626815


P3
A
WEEK 1
-0.4598198


P3
A
WEEK 5
0.5334187


P3
A
WEEK 9
-1.0935954


P3
A
WEEK 13
-0.4647637


P3
A
WEEK 21
0.3149923


P3
A
WEEK 29
-0.1895424


P4
B
WEEK 1
-0.5114456


P4
B
WEEK 5
-1.3369919


P4
B
WEEK 9
-0.1792270


P4
B
WEEK 13
0.6105136


P4
B
WEEK 21
0.7945704


P4
B
WEEK 29
-0.7455857


P4
B
WEEK 37
-0.1885796


P4
B
WEEK 45
-0.0296351


P5
A
WEEK 1
-0.6016414


P5
A
WEEK 5
-0.7907177


P5
A
WEEK 9
0.5272764


P5
A
WEEK 13
-0.7072240


P5
A
WEEK 21
-0.8007317


P5
A
WEEK 29
0.2442433


P5
A
WEEK 37
0.8091940


P5
A
WEEK 45
1.1674545


P6
B
WEEK 1
-0.3438111


P6
B
WEEK 5
0.9949341


P7
B
WEEK 1
0.3359617


P7
B
WEEK 5
-1.5204856


P7
B
WEEK 9
1.4748533


P7
B
WEEK 13
-0.1804012


P7
B
WEEK 21
-0.1968636


P7
B
WEEK 29
-1.3816777


P7
B
WEEK 37
-0.2774994


P7
B
WEEK 41
0.4935704


P8
B
WEEK 1
0.5820643


P8
B
WEEK 5
0.5845221


P8
B
WEEK 9
-0.4113974


P8
B
WEEK 13
1.9424362


P9
A
WEEK 1
-0.0273660


P9
A
WEEK 5
-0.7306722


P9
A
WEEK 9
-0.7650743


P9
A
WEEK 13
2.3694216


P9
A
WEEK 21
0.8118095


P9
A
WEEK 29
0.3028293


P9
A
WEEK 37
-0.4808068


P9
A
WEEK 45
1.7521192


P10
A
WEEK 1
1.5217938


P10
A
WEEK 5
-0.9806086


P10
A
WEEK 9
-1.0966349


P10
A
WEEK 13
-1.9008262


P10
A
WEEK 21
-1.5658725


P10
A
WEEK 29
1.5972766


P11
B
WEEK 1
0.3776805


P11
B
WEEK 5
-1.0314852


P11
B
WEEK 9
0.2206801


P11
B
WEEK 13
-1.2647146


P11
B
WEEK 21
-0.3237898


P12
A
WEEK 1
1.6249765


P12
A
WEEK 5
0.0398747


P12
A
WEEK 9
0.5680598


P12
A
WEEK 13
-0.3360392


P12
A
WEEK 21
-0.2111337


P13
A
WEEK 1
0.4426254


P13
A
WEEK 5
-1.2204266


P13
A
WEEK 9
-0.1722378


P13
A
WEEK 13
-1.5916035


P13
A
WEEK 21
1.5706844


P13
A
WEEK 29
1.3931773


P13
A
WEEK 37
-0.7687676


P13
A
WEEK 45
-0.3492070


P14
B
WEEK 1
-1.2492349


P14
B
WEEK 5
1.0534678


P15
A
WEEK 1
0.9449768


P15
A
WEEK 5
0.8109831


P15
A
WEEK 13
-0.2970762


P16
B
WEEK 1
1.0128413


P16
B
WEEK 5
0.1341700


P17
B
WEEK 1
0.3807200


P17
B
WEEK 5
1.5646068


P17
B
WEEK 9
-1.0134616


P18
B
WEEK 1
-0.3509063


P18
B
WEEK 5
-0.6523584


P18
B
WEEK 9
-0.4991037


P18
B
WEEK 13
2.2372360


P19
A
WEEK 1
0.6149147


P19
A
WEEK 5
-1.5269506


P19
A
WEEK 9
1.2117663


P19
A
WEEK 13
0.8854084


P20
B
WEEK 1
-0.7359162


P20
B
WEEK 5
0.5060897


P21
A
WEEK 1
1.5166838


P21
A
WEEK 5
1.0669268


P21
A
WEEK 9
0.1458909


P21
A
WEEK 13
0.8524727


P22
B
WEEK 1
-1.5117311


P22
B
WEEK 5
1.3048330


P22
B
WEEK 9
-0.6675805


P23
A
WEEK 1
-0.6330985


P23
A
WEEK 5
0.2631228


P23
A
WEEK 9
0.1202108


P23
A
WEEK 13
-1.7309419


P23
A
WEEK 21
-0.4410481


P23
A
WEEK 29
-2.6044729


P23
A
WEEK 37
3.0068373


P23
A
WEEK 45
-0.0433140


P24
B
WEEK 1
0.7382375


P24
B
WEEK 5
-0.1817289


P24
B
WEEK 9
0.0463616


P24
B
WEEK 13
-0.7516783


P25
A
WEEK 1
-0.4641330


P25
A
WEEK 5
1.1938924


P25
A
WEEK 9
-0.0388219


P25
A
WEEK 13
0.3832291


P26
B
WEEK 1
0.9438905


P26
B
WEEK 5
1.2972308


P26
B
WEEK 9
3.0206015


P27
B
WEEK 1
-2.2556081


P27
B
WEEK 5
-0.2908092


P27
B
WEEK 9
1.1114844


P27
B
WEEK 13
1.3005622


P27
B
WEEK 21
0.2601997


P28
A
WEEK 1
2.3824005


P28
A
WEEK 5
1.6715523


P28
A
WEEK 9
-0.0419464


P28
A
WEEK 13
-0.4536449


P28
A
WEEK 21
0.5327198


P28
A
WEEK 29
0.9289475


P28
A
WEEK 37
-0.1071874


P28
A
WEEK 45
-0.2667674


P29
B
WEEK 1
2.0830940


P29
B
WEEK 5
1.1413462


P30
A
WEEK 1
-0.4406052


P30
A
WEEK 5
-1.9685028


P30
A
WEEK 9
-1.6008250


P30
A
WEEK 13
0.3193410


P30
A
WEEK 21
-0.4659043


P30
A
WEEK 29
0.3440616


P31
A
WEEK 1
0.4376565


P31
A
WEEK 5
1.3290369


P31
A
WEEK 9
1.5437684


P31
A
WEEK 13
0.3957487


P32
B
WEEK 1
-0.5172986


P32
B
WEEK 5
-0.4852826


P32
B
WEEK 9
0.9713095


P32
B
WEEK 13
0.6769045


P32
B
WEEK 21
1.6999939


P32
B
WEEK 29
1.2371956


P32
B
WEEK 37
0.6988146


P32
B
WEEK 45
0.3193445


P33
B
WEEK 1
1.3498176


P33
B
WEEK 5
0.2302169


P33
B
WEEK 9
1.0374081


P34
B
WEEK 1
0.7550728


P35
A
WEEK 1
1.5003623


P35
A
WEEK 5
-0.0927840


P35
A
WEEK 9
0.2954815


P35
A
WEEK 13
-1.0958777


P35
A
WEEK 21
-0.2362034


P35
A
WEEK 29
-0.5146772


P35
A
WEEK 37
0.2146659


P35
A
WEEK 45
0.7603413


P36
B
WEEK 1
1.7959577


P36
B
WEEK 5
-1.1342839


P36
B
WEEK 9
-0.3609796


P36
B
WEEK 13
-2.7764579


P36
B
WEEK 21
-0.9022042


P37
A
WEEK 1
0.4487893


P37
A
WEEK 5
0.3774568


P37
A
WEEK 9
-2.0969882


P37
A
WEEK 13
0.4484431


P37
A
WEEK 21
-0.0279065


P37
A
WEEK 29
0.7918710


P37
A
WEEK 37
-0.9219268


P37
A
WEEK 45
0.2214336


P38
B
WEEK 1
0.2281167


P38
B
WEEK 5
0.5263752


P39
A
WEEK 1
-0.3489746


P39
A
WEEK 5
1.1682846


P39
A
WEEK 9
0.6347751


P39
A
WEEK 13
-0.4259921


P40
A
WEEK 1
0.6337292


P40
A
WEEK 5
1.7915169


P40
A
WEEK 9
0.7809711


P41
B
WEEK 1
-1.8568523


P41
B
WEEK 5
0.4308115


P41
B
WEEK 9
-0.2384108


P42
B
WEEK 1
-2.1578197


P42
B
WEEK 5
0.4233963


P43
B
WEEK 1
0.5454538


P43
B
WEEK 5
0.0800674


P43
B
WEEK 9
0.8325559


P44
A
WEEK 1
0.3570891


P44
A
WEEK 5
0.8941482


P44
A
WEEK 13
-1.8330631


P44
A
WEEK 21
0.1658695


P45
B
WEEK 1
0.6179838


P45
B
WEEK 5
0.7497043


P46
B
WEEK 1
0.0588064


P46
B
WEEK 5
-0.7555071


P47
A
WEEK 1
-0.3244597


P47
A
WEEK 5
-0.0226275


P47
A
WEEK 9
0.4983639


P47
A
WEEK 13
0.0012752


P47
A
WEEK 21
-1.7876090


P47
A
WEEK 29
0.2893496


P48
A
WEEK 1
1.0647324


P48
A
WEEK 5
-1.6050369


P48
A
WEEK 13
0.5360071


P48
A
WEEK 21
0.8505539


P48
A
WEEK 29
1.0809360


P48
A
WEEK 37
-1.9553655


P48
A
WEEK 45
1.6910142


P49
B
WEEK 1
0.0351847


P49
B
WEEK 5
0.7622782


P49
B
WEEK 9
-0.1448169


P49
B
WEEK 13
-0.9234882


P49
B
WEEK 21
-0.3360023


P49
B
WEEK 29
1.0721855


P49
B
WEEK 37
0.4221931


P50
B
WEEK 1
0.4078645


P50
B
WEEK 5
-0.5976864


P50
B
WEEK 9
-0.9666003


P51
B
WEEK 1
1.2969588


P51
B
WEEK 5
-0.3586442


P51
B
WEEK 9
-0.0974125


P51
B
WEEK 13
0.1359142


P52
A
WEEK 1
-0.0290009


P52
A
WEEK 5
-0.3977555


P52
A
WEEK 9
-0.4833838


P52
A
WEEK 13
0.5380669


P52
A
WEEK 21
-0.3991081


P52
A
WEEK 29
1.0105654


P53
A
WEEK 1
0.6690505


P53
A
WEEK 5
3.2405680


P53
A
WEEK 9
2.5401370


P53
A
WEEK 13
0.6123937


P54
A
WEEK 1
0.4485402


P54
A
WEEK 5
-0.0357942


P54
A
WEEK 9
0.9773253


P54
A
WEEK 13
-0.8614580


P54
A
WEEK 21
-0.8414761


P54
A
WEEK 29
0.3636426


P54
A
WEEK 37
0.4034867


P54
A
WEEK 45
-0.2861775


P55
A
WEEK 1
0.2348440


P55
A
WEEK 5
1.4555923


P55
A
WEEK 13
-2.2273128


P56
A
WEEK 1
0.0486827


P56
A
WEEK 5
0.9241710


P56
A
WEEK 9
2.0332698


P56
A
WEEK 13
-2.5866847


P56
A
WEEK 21
1.2839924




Hi @Nin00, interesting question - I believe it is more about emmeans here. Have you tried posting this on their GitHub repository as an issue already? https://github.com/rvlenth/emmeans/issues
